# Wiped System Partition... No OS.. How can I recover it back?

Tags: twrp, partitions, system, operating-system

I successfully installed TWRP yesterday on my phone and then wanted to root it, but before doing that, I wanted to do a Full-Wipe of my phone, just leaving the phone with the OS, but for some reason, I left the System Partition Wipe option enabled and Wiped it. Now, I'm stuck in a bootloop without an OS, and I can only access TWRP and Download Mode.

How can I recover the system/install the OS again?

Phone Specs:

SAMSUNG J7 PRO (SM-J730GM),

Previous O.S: Nougat 7.0

Region: México TCE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Download the following file (J730GMTCE2AQJ1_TCE) from [samfirmware.com](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-j7-pro/SM-J730GM/TCE/confirm/J730GMUBU2AQJ2/192525/): [direct link](https://dl.sammobile.com/Pl9aQy4-ISowXCQmOVo2PkNbWTQkJzctVy80PUI3PTcxRhMaGUlOOyhDL0BAWC45TlJYSltGRl1fVAMWHxsMTk5eXkFQRUVe/J730GMUBU2AQJ2_J730GMTCE2AQJ1_TCE.zip)
2. Extract (unzip) the firmware file
3. [Download Odin v3.12.7](https://dl.sammobile.com/Odin3-v3.12.7.zip)
4. Open Odin v3.12.7 (make sure to *Run as administrator*)
5. Reboot your SAMSUNG J7 PRO (SM-J730GM) into Download Mode (press and hold Home + Power + Volume Down buttons)
6. Connect phone and wait until you get a blue sign in Odin
7. Add the firmware file to AP / PDA
8. Make sure re-partition is **NOT** ticked
9. Click the start button, sit back and wait few minutes for it to install the stock operating system.

[Instructions source](https://www.sammobile.com/firmwares/galaxy-j7-pro/SM-J730GM/TCE/confirm/J730GMUBU2AQJ2/192525/) (personally tested on another Samsung device)

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm going to try this, but I was wondering... what if I was already downloading that file with the SamFirm Tool, since I don't have any username on that page? Is it the same file?

EDIT: I will update here If I have any complications :)

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Now I'm going back to install TWRP and root it without deleting the system partition